# How is this JavaScript working in an email received from Google

Tags: javascript, html, email

I received an email in my Gmail account from Google about people I might know on Google+ which contained running JavaScript with hover effects etc, at least I assume it was JavaScript, HTML5 maybe??... See below screenshot:

[image]

As you can see (kind of) is when I hovered over the `ADD TO CIRCLES` button, a new window slid open asking me to select a category for that person. When I ticked a category, it added a Tag with that category next to the persons name.

I have never seen an email with dynamic content like this, and I am guessing the obvious answer the email was from Google being displayed on they own email service so they can do what they like. But I would be interested in how they achieved this and could we take advantage of it in some way?

Comment: Look at the source of the email. The JavaScript will be there, if any. And no, it's not just Google that can do that, anyone can include JavaScript in their mails.

Comment: Could be done using css transformations I guess. What does a click on one of the items do? Just pop some URL open?

Comment: Customized emails are just html pages, you can include whatever you want (js, css, etc...)

Comment: The email does not contain Javascript, the html elements the email contains have certain classes that the Gmail site code picks up and uses. Click the "Show Original" option in the More menu and you will see the exact contents of the email

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I have never seen working JavaScript in an Email, it's always stripped isn't it?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I thought that might be the case, does that mean I could compose an email using these classes and ID's and Gmail would do the same thing? Something tells me not, but I'll give it a go...

Comment: @m02ph3u5 When you click on one of the items it actually ticks and then sticks a tag with that item label next to the persons name, the more you tick the more tags appear next to the persons name.

Comment: Ah, it's inside the Gmail web application, so it's possible that Gmail does recognize the message as originating from Google+ and adds the extra behaviour. However, it's still possible to do this with JavaScript within an email. It is not stripped, that's entirely up to the receiving part (e.g., my mail client disables JavaScript execution by default, but I can turn it on and get such behaviour; it's not that difficult to write JavaScript in emails).